# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (the doctor check crashed). on macbook m1 pro

Tags: macos, flutter, apple-m1

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. The doctor check crashed with this error:

```
✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message
  below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
✗ FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 5)
• #0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle
  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1788:7)
  #1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:318:42)
  #2      InputStream.readString
  (package:archive/src/util/input_stream.dart:199:30)
  #3      new ZipDirectory.read
  (package:archive/src/zip/zip_directory.dart:40:30)
  #4      ZipDecoder.decodeBuffer
  (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:19:30)
  #5      ZipDecoder.decodeBytes
  (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:14:12)
  #6      IntelliJPlugins._findPluginXml
  (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:130:44)
  #7      IntelliJPlugins._readPackageVersion
  (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:141:40)
  #8      IntelliJPlugins.validatePackage
  (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:63:35)
  #9      IntelliJValidator.validate
  (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij_validator.dart:103:15)
  #10     asyncGuard.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:32)
  #11     asyncGuard.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:18)
  #12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
  #13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
  #14     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
  #15     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
  #16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1782:12)
  #17     asyncGuard (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:3)
  #18     Doctor.startValidatorTasks
  (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:200:9)
  #19     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:304:47)
  #20     DoctorCommand.runCommand
  (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:50:47)
  #21     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
  (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1274:12)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #22     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #23     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #24     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #25     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #26     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #27     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
  (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #28     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #29     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #30     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
  <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is tracked at
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5872
Intellij also points to the github issue

Comment: To clarify: 1) this issue does not have an impact on our daily work, everything seems to work as usual even with this error in 'flutter doctor'; 2) The original Github issue that tracks this problem is that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94060